# ZFS support for linux kernel versions 3.16

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, zfs

Attempting to boot Funtoo with a [debian-sources-3.16.2-3](https://github.com/funtoo/ports-2012/blob/funtoo.org/sys-kernel/debian-sources/debian-sources-3.16.2.ebuild) kernel, in a system where the root file-system lives in a zpool, drops off to the rescue shell after failing to import the pool properly. **Does ZFS-on-Linux support linux-kernel versions 3.16.y?**

The official [related FAQ](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhatKernelVersionsAreSupported) states:

> The current spl/zfs-0.6.3 release supports Linux 2.6.26 - 3.15
>   kernels.

However, in a [related post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8306618), someone wrote:

> ZoL provides the latest code to all supported kernels and
>   distributions. This ranges from Linux 2.6.26.y to the 3.16.y in 0.6.3
>   and will include 3.17.y in 0.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a typo in the the `real_root=ZFS=` parameter in `grub.cfg`. After fixing it, the system boot successfully.

So,

- [zfs-0.6.3](http://archive.zfsonlinux.org/downloads/zfsonlinux/zfs/zfs-0.6.3.tar.gz) **does** support kernel versions 3.16.y
- there is a "typo" in the [related FAQ](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhatKernelVersionsAreSupported)

Comment: Typo in http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhatKernelVersionsAreSupported fixed.