# How can I detect whether an "NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup" is a hardware or a software issue?

Tags: linux-kernel, zfs, bugs

### Soft Lockup

`dmesg` reports in my laptop, since quite some time now, `NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup` *every time* I try to use `updatedb` or `firefox`. Samples of what is reported posted at https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/4536#issuecomment-280894134.

**Related questions** are

- [What is a CPU soft lockup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303062/13011)
- [What does "kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup" followed by other errors mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216959/13011)
- [Kernel Crash/ Cpu error?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282316/13011)

I have also read/commented at
 - https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/4536

### Question

How can I detect whether it's a hardware issue or, as I think, confirm it's an issue related to the kernel/software?

---

### Details

#### Linux Distribution

[Funtoo-Linux](http://www.funtoo.org), a rolling distribution

#### Kernels

I have (at least) observed the "BUG" while using the following kernel(s) versions:

[pf](https://pf.natalenko.name/)

- 4.11_p4-pf
- 4.8_p8
- 4.5_p4

[ck](http://users.tpg.com.au/ckolivas/kernel/)

- 4.12.7-ck

[debian](http://www.debian.org)

- lts-4.9.30
- 4.8.x
- 4.7.8

#### Configuration

I use a custom configuration to compile the kernel. It's mostly the same configuration I use(d) for long time, when there was no "soft lockup" problem or whatsoever related to a "watchdog".

I can copy-paste or link the configuration file. However, two important settings I have found else to be "required"

```
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE=y
```

#### ZFS

I observed the "BUG" while using ZoL versions

- 0.6.5.11
- 0.6.5.10
- 0.6.5.9
- 0.6.5.8
- 0.6.5.3

Comment: NMI by definition is a hw interrupt; it manifesting itself only on those two programs, could it be load related, have you tried other heavy I/O programs?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The OP is not asking what NMI is but what *caused* the watchdog to be woken up (IOW what caused the kernel to be stuck)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I really want to know whether my laptop needs a hardware service or if I am messing too much with my custom kernel configurations. But, yes, I got the "BUG" also once using a simple `find` command that was finding too many files.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro And if useful, I have tried (in the past) an Ubuntu-Live version. It did not cause the CPU to stale.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Using ZFS in linux in that machine. please add distro , version, kernel version and zfs version.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I've added details. If more required, please help me understanding what is useful to report.

Comment: I am getting the picture. but have to ask, why zfs in a notebook?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro To learn and have fun with it in the beginning. Now because it's neat! See also http://www.funtoo.org/ZFS_Fun.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it could be a hardware problem, however due to the *code maturity* of the [ZFS code for Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/), and a whole slew of people complaining of your very same message in multiple versions, I am inclined to say that is a software bug.

There have been multiple bugs about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in the ZFS code, and truth is that is not still entirely trustworthy for production systems.

If that notebook of yours is a playground/testing system, a good ZFS test to possibly rule out software versus hardware problems  would be trying ZFS+[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/), which has a more tested and stable codebase.

If you also had in the past a known stable config with Linux+zfs, as per your aditional comments, it could be a good idea to go back and test it, for ruling out *possible* problems.

As for trying to debug the actual kernel level code, you could try [`sysdig`](https://www.sysdig.org/) but if the system hangs, it is possible it dies on you before spewing logs that can lead to the root of the problem (or not).

Comment: Thank you. This is meant to be a way to test for hardware vs. software? Is there really no other way to capture what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: This https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157413/13011 I wrote when there was no problem. Perhaps I should try to get that kernel (3.x.x) and ZFS (0.6.3) running again?

Comment: Sorry, did read well your comment. added to the answer.

Comment: I am not sure if ZFS 0.6.3 (ZoL) can see my current pool anymore. Before I try this, I'd better confirm that this old version will support a pool which has feature flags.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Yeah, there is always the problem of versions features.

Comment: I will try yet with another live version, which supports for ZFS.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Seems a good plan.

Comment: Tried with an Lubuntu Live USB. There is no problem "there". Firefox is working properly, `updatedb` as well. Importing my "zpool" worked flawlessly. The blame is on me and the custom kernel configuration I use. Of course, I don't know what exactly is my wrongdoing.